# How to implement a popup dialogue in React Native application?

Tags: javascript, react-native, jsx

In my react native project I list a bunch of posts and a user can 'like' one or more posts if they want. I require the user to input their password the first time they like a post.  I'm new to react native and I'm unsure how I present the user with either a dialogue or new page so they can enter their password and then the original screen listing the posts shows after this.

I have a touchable component associated with each post that has an onPress event:

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => Util.vote(props.info)}>
.......
</TouchableHighlight>
```

So it calls a function `vote()` where I will put the password logic.  Can I output JSX from a function like this?  If so how do I do that so that afterwards it returns to the original list of posts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to implement popup dialogue is [react-native-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal).

refer the snippet

```
<TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.setState({ showPasswordModal: true })>
.......
</TouchableHighlight>
.....
<Modal
   isVisible={this.state.showPasswordModal}
   style={....}>
   <View>
        ...layout to get password
   </View>
</Modal>
```

In the first line on the press, we are opening the modal which contains get password layout using state variable.

After getting a password and verifying it, we can close the modal using the same state variable and continue with the code.

refer [react-native-modal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-modal) library.

If need more information, please revert back to me.